# Reconstruct Binary Search Tree From Inorder and Preorder

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

How can I draw a Binary Search Tree using below data.

Inorder :- `C, B, D, A, E, G, H, F`

Preorder :- `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H`

Is there any generic algorithm? Can anyone help me to solve this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the preorder, we can infer that `A` is a *root* of the tree.
2. Then from the inorder, we can infer that `C B D` form the *left sub-tree*, and `E G H F` form the *right sub-tree*.
3. Consider the *left sub-tree* consists of `C B D`:

   1. From  the preorder, we can infer that `B` is the root. And then from the inorder, we know that `C` and `D` are the *left child* and *right child* respectively.
4. Consider the *right sub-tree* consists of `E G H F`:

   1. From the preorder, we can infer that `E` is the root; and from the inorder, `G H F` belong to the *right sub-tree*.
   2. Consider the *sub-tree* `G H F`:

      1. The preorder tells us that `F` is the root, and from the inorder, we can infer that `G H` belong to the *left sub-tree* of `F`
      2. Consider `G H`:

         1. From preorder, `G` is the root and `H` is the *right child*

Therefore the tree is given below:

```
       A
      / \
     B   E
    / \   \
   C   D   F
          /
         G
          \
           H
```